# IBM Worklight and Desktop Application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, desktop

Can I create an App that can be deployed both on Windows 7/8 desktop and also  mobile devices( iOS, Android and Windows 7.0 ) with the same/single code base.

Can I deploy single codebase hybrid app both on Win and mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Windows PHONE 7 - no. This platform is no longer supported starting Worklight 6.2 and above

If you are talking about Windows 7 widgets for Desktop - no. This platform is no longer supported since... Worklight 6.0(?) or so.

Windows 8 is supported.

The concept behind Worklight/MobileFirst Platform is that indeed your application to the various (supported) platform will indeed have a common (shared) codebase, that you can further tweak when required, per platform.